# Embed Experience cloud pages as iframe in external web site

Tags: visualforce, community, lightning-community, experience-cloud, clickjacking

We need to integrate Experience Cloud (Community) page content in an external website owned by our client.

The Experience Cloud (Lightning Community) is active and found under a sub-domain (custom domain) of the external web site itself.

Basically, we want to display Salesforce data in a lightning component on the external website, after the community user has authenticated to the community.

But as per this article [Integration of Experience Builder Site into External Websites Using iframes Not Supported](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000314402&type=1) :

> It is important to note that Experience Builder site do not support  integration into customers’ external websites.

> If an iframe implementation approach is a strict business requirement then you can opt for a Visualforce site.

Visualforce being "obsolete" as a new implementation and even if we can embed Lightning component in the visualforce using Lightning Out, we are concerned with security ([Clickjack protection](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_clickjack_protection.htm&type=5)) and performance risks.

**Questions** :

1. Is Visualforce the only solution as iframe in external website ?
2. If yes, can the Visualforce page reside in the same active Lightning community with "*Allow framing by the same origin only (recommended)*" settings enabled since the community is in subdomain of external website ?

Any other recommendation is appreciated

Comment: My recommendation: step away from any hope to use iframes to embed any Lightning pages (community or otherwise). We have Visualforce pages embedded in an external site via iframes, but found it impossible to move to Lightning Experience (things like list views etc. try to open in Lightning and this cannot be embedded in an iframe). We hit a complete roadblock on this; Salesforce won't allow trusted site config to control enabling this so we must now totally change our "integration" to avoid direct iframes altogether. I don't know if LWR or OSS LWC would get around this for you...?

Comment: @PhilW Thanks for your feedback. so in your case, the community is "Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce", right ? 
Do you know if we can keep our lightning community and add visualforce under pages section of the site and still have recommended settings for clickjack ?
I will look into LWR and open source LWC